# code not working on Android 4.2 but ok on Android 2.3

Tags: android, version

I have a set of code that is working ok on android 2.3 but not on 4.2 emulator. This is a slideout menu code with a set of tabhost in it. The slideout menu code was downloaded from [here](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation) . Can  somebody please tell me what is my problem.

Here is my code:

```
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import android.app.TabActivity; 
    import com.korovyansk.android.slideout.SlideoutActivity;

    public class SampleActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

    TabHost tabHost;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(16)
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
        findViewById(R.id.sample_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SlideoutActivity.prepare  (SampleActivity.this, R.id.inner_content, width);
        startActivity(new Intent(SampleActivity.this,MenuActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    }
                }); 

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


    // Tab for ID 
    TabSpec IDspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ID"); 
    IDspec.setIndicator("My e-ID", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_id)); 
    Intent MyEidIntent = new Intent(this, MyEidActivity.class); 
    IDspec.setContent(MyEidIntent); 

    // Tab for Verify_Me
    TabSpec VerifyMespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Verify_Me"); 
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab 
    VerifyMespec.setIndicator("Verify Me", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_verify_me)); 
    Intent VerifyMeIntent = new Intent(this, VerifyMeActivity.class); 
    VerifyMespec.setContent(VerifyMeIntent); 

    // Tab for Verify Other 
    TabSpec VerifyOthersspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Verify_Others");         
    VerifyOthersspec.setIndicator("Verify Others", getResources().getDrawabl(R.drawable.ic_verify_other)); 
    Intent VerifyOtherIntent = new Intent(this, VerifyOtherActivity.class); 
    VerifyOthersspec.setContent(VerifyOtherIntent); 

    // Tab for Scan
    TabSpec Scanspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Scan");         
    Scanspec.setIndicator("Scan", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_verify_other)); 
    Intent ScanspecIntent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class); 
    Scanspec.setContent(ScanspecIntent); 



 // Tab for Setting
    TabSpec Settingspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Setting"); 
    Settingspec.setIndicator("Setting", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_setting)); 
    Intent SettingIntent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class); 
    Settingspec.setContent(SettingIntent); 




    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost 

    tabHost.addTab(IDspec);
    tabHost.addTab(VerifyMespec); // Adding photos tab 
    tabHost.addTab(VerifyOthersspec); // Adding songs tab 
    tabHost.addTab(Scanspec); // Adding videos tab 
    tabHost.addTab(Settingspec);

    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
     {
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0FFFF"));

     TextView x = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        x.setTextSize(10);
        x.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 


  }  


   tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#adff87"));
   TextView y = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
   y.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
   tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    @Override

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        TabHost tabHost= getTabHost();


        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0FFFF"));
            TextView x = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            x.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
        } 

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor("#adff87")); 
        TextView y = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).findViewById(android.R.id.title);    
        y.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    }

    }
```

The logcat is here

```
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.e_idglobal/com.e_idglobal.SampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at com.e_idglobal.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:34)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-12 06:47:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1405):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.e_idglobal.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:34)` On line 34 of onCreate there is a NPE

Comment: @Benjanmin, Line 34 is if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
      getActionBar().hide();
     }. I suspect this may be the case as this relate to version of Android. But don't know where. Thanks

Comment: Try to split this line into two - the `if` and the `getActionBar()...` , it´s probably easier to find the error this way - after that, put breakpoints there, and see in which line it crashes, then update your question with a stacktrace/logcat and the line where the crash occurs

Comment: @Benjamin, i have redone as you suggested. I have .hide() in a seperate line. Logcat suggest it is here. Looks like the ActionBar can not be hided. This is ok in Version 2.3 as it doesn't have ActionBar. So how we can fix it.

Comment: If you want to have your `ActionBar` removed all the time, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing), this might be what you need

Comment: And by the way, a general adive: try to **not** suppress warnings as they usually have a reason, but try to find out how to solve these problems instead of ignoring them

Comment: thanks, i remove the hide(), it workded. i think may be because in the it already set in manifest as notitlebar

Answer (score 0):

```
VerifyOthersspec.setIndicator("Verify Others", getResources().getDrawabl(R.drawable.ic_verify_other));
```

Here it is: getDrawabl(...);
Add the *e* and it should work.

This should have been shown by Eclipse though.

Comment: sorry i must have accidently deleted the e. It is in my Eclipse.